# Add query string if there is none

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, redirect

Is it possible to check if a page has a query string and then add one if it doesn't?

I'm currently using a 301 redirect but I'm was wondering if there was a quicker / cleaner method?

Example: If a user goes to `website.com/referral`, then they're redirected to `website.com/referral?code`.

If a user goes to `website.com/referral?code2`, then they're not redirected.

Thank you!

EDIT: I don't mind whether it be client side or server side, but I'd prefer to use whatever method is the cleanest and effects the user the least.

EDIT 2: 
Here's my htaccess after trying to use a rewite rule. However when visiting /referral nothing happens.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^referral/?$ /referral.php?123

Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 /404.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php


# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]


# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]


RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Do you want it to be client side or server side?

Comment: Do you want a Javascript solution?

Comment: It doesn't really matter. I'd prefer to use whatever is the cleanest.

Comment: I'm currently using a 301 redirect but was wondering if there was anything which was less messy / quicker for the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it on the server side to avoid the extra page load using mod_rewrite. Check if `%QUERY_STRING` is empty (compare it to `^$`), if it is, redirect to another page. If it isn't, do nothing:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^referral/?$ /referral.php?code
```

[%{QUERY_STRING} reference](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for me. I've added my current htaccess as an edit to the original post

Comment: You’ll probably need to reorder some of the rules. The `L` flag tells Apache to stop checking the following rules if it’s matched, so it might not be going through.

Comment: I've moved it up to the top yet it still doesn't seem to be working. I appreciate the help!

Comment: How about adding the L flag to that rule? Maybe it’s still hitting that catch-all rule you have at the bottom. Also, whats the exact URL it’s supposed to be? Is it actually /referral (as in, the root of the domain)?

Comment: Adding the L didn't help. And yes, the url is     `https://www.website.com/referral`

Comment: Hmm it’s a little difficult helping you debug this in the dark. My last try would be to remove all other rules, i.e. leave only the first three lines in the file and check if it’s working then. Then, debug from there.

Comment: Even after removing everything it still doesn't seem to be working. I guess it's an issue elsewhere. Anyway, thanks for the help! It's much appreciated!

Comment: Last shot: add a leading slash (all your other rules have it), `RewriteRule ^/?referral/?$ /referral?code`

Comment: Also, try the rule with the extensions (.php), since that other rule you removed was responsible for redirecting files without extensions.

Comment: Did a lot of messing around today and managed to get your code to work. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: I'm so glad to hear that! :)

Answer (score 0):

## Widow location

If `window.location.search` returns an empty string then there is no query param.

You can then set the query param with this line `window.location.search = "key=value"`

### Note

- If you do this the page will refresh.
- It is fully supported across major browsers see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_search.asp)
- The answer given here assumes that you have access to the window object (ie: you are client side)
- This solution will be kind of "dirty" as well since it will load the page and then redirect since its client side (A better way to handle this would be on the server)